# Using RESTful API and Django: how to temporarily add data into backend?

Tags: javascript, sql, django, api

I am currently building a webapp (that will be presented as a single site eventually) using django and sqlite - the goal is to present an interactive front end where the user is able to see a randomized sample of the data I am storing.

At this point I have a working connection between the sql database and what is presented in the views, but the way I have it set up I must enter the data manually.

I would like to use an API (NYTimes) to automatically be called upon a few times a day, store what is given from the API, and present it on a basic JavaScript page. I was thinking the best method would be to call GET from the API in the JavaScript file of the view, and then load it into the backend --- and this is where I get a bit lost.  (As you can tell I am new at this)  I have tried searching for a method like this, but nothing seems to do quite what I need.

If I am missing anything big or if you have any suggestions/solutions, I would love to hear! -- Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What you can use here is django-extensions https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions it lets you run arbitrary scripts in the context of django, i.e. allows you to read and write to database using django ORM.

You can write the script to get the data from the API and dump it into the database, setup a cron to run this at intervals you like.